# Calculate the time difference between clicks on two different buttons

Tags: php, html, database

I need to calculate the time passed between the first click on a start button and a second click on a finish button. I need it to be in the format h:m:s. And I need to save the time with PHP but don't know how.

Comment: You need to do this in JavaScript on the front-end.

Comment: Here's for the javascript part with visible feedback https://stackoverflow.com/a/73505998/3807365

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```html
  <button id="start">START</button>
  <button id="end">END</button>



  <script>
    let startBtn = document.querySelector("#start")
    let endBtn = document.querySelector("#end")


    let startTimeStamp;
    let result;


    startBtn.onclick = (e) => {
      startTimeStamp = e.timeStamp;
    }
    endBtn.onclick = (e) => {
      result = e.timeStamp - startTimeStamp;
      result = formatResult(result);
      console.log(result)
      sendResult(result);
    }

    function formatResult(ms) {
      let seconds = Math.floor(ms / 1000);
      let minutes = Math.floor(seconds / 60);
      let hours = Math.floor(minutes / 60);

      seconds = seconds % 60;
      minutes = minutes % 60;

      hours = hours.toString().length == 1 ? "0" + hours : hours;
      minutes = minutes.toString().length == 1 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
      seconds = seconds.toString().length == 1 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

      return `${hours}:${minutes}:${seconds}`;
    }

    function sendResult(result) {
      let formData = new FormData()
      formData.append("result", result)

      fetch("index.php", { method: "POST", body: formData }).then(res => res.text().then(res => console.log(res)))
    }
  
  
  </script>
```

then in php:

```
<?php

$mysqli = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "db");

mysqli_query("INSERT INTO [table] values('$_POST[result]')");

?>
```